# Can I display admob Native ads along with admob Banner ad in same activity?

Tags: android, admob, ads, adbannerview

I had made an app with tab layout. Can I insert an Admob Banner ad in bottom and AdMob or facebook native ad in all other fragments? Is this against any AdMob policy. Thanks for Answer in advanced.

Comment: . read this article https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287 to understand Admob Discouraged policy for banner implementation

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can.
Major restrictions : user interface must not be changed accidentally. And the user have to understand that this rectange is banner (ad).

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions, even we can use two native ads on same activity.
Like this we can use native and banner in the same activity, i've tried.